# What is "piggul"? A question on the Bartenura

Tags: korban, mishna, bartenura

The Mishna (Zevachim 2:3) clearly defines *piggul* (פגול) as resulting from one of the four sacrificial procedures (slaughter, collection of the blood, walking to the altar and sprinkling) being performed with the intention of eating the sacrifice after its appointed time *only*. Something that is slaughtered (or has its blood collected, carried or sprinkled) on condition that it be eaten outside of its appointed *place* is also forbidden, but it is not called *piggul* and it does not result in *karet*.

This same attitude is expressly clearly in the Rambam (Hilkhot Pesulei haMuqdashin 13:1) - any sacrifice that is performed with the intention of its being eaten outside the appointed place is forbidden, but only that which is performed with the intention if its being eaten outside of its appointed *time* is called *piggul*.

I am not aware of anybody holding contrary to this, and yet consider what the Bartenura says on Kareitot 1:1! There, the mishna includes the consumption of *piggul* as one of the thirty-six things that results in *karet*, and the Bartenura defines *piggul* as follows:

קדשים שחשב לאכלן חוץ לזמנן או חוץ למקומן

Sacrifices, [during the performance of which] one intended to eat of them outside the appointed time, *or outside the appointed place*.

Is this a typo in the Bartenura?? I've checked two different versions already, and this is what he says in both of them. Not only that, but I've not found anybody else commenting upon the phenomenon. Assuming it is not a mistake, how can the Bartenura define *piggul* contrary to the Rambam, the gemara and the Mishna itself?

Comment: I remember the Yerushalmi in Pesachim through Rabbi Yochanan go in more detail on Piggul. I do not recall where at the moment. I learned this a few years ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  עיקר תוי"ט already asks your question [ibid](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01338.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)

> **ח:** וְדִבְרֵי תֵּימַהּ הֵן, דִּבְהֶדְיָא שָׁנִינוּ בְּמִשְׁנָה ג' פֶּרֶק ב' דִּזְבָחִים חוּץ לִמְקוֹמוֹ פָּסוּל וְאֵין בּוֹ כָּרֵת‏

So it seems that the Bartenura was either badly copied or else simply used the common phrase  חוץ לזמנן או חוץ למקומן "as a matter of habit".

(For similar, see the  עיקר תוי"ט on ברכות  Ch. 4 note (יא) where he also says אגב רהיטא לא דק דהול"ל והתפללו אליך דרך העיר. So it happens that the Bartenura can't be taken *literally*.)

Comment: Thankyou! That's a little embarrassing, since I actually thought that I'd checked the Tosafot Yom Tov, and I evidentally didn't look hard enough! Now that I do, I see that the Ahavat Eytan and Tiferet Yisrael comment on this too. The latter, incidentally, thinks that חוץ למקומו is a type of *piggul*. That still doesn't answer why it should be included here if it doesn't cause *karet*, but I'll see what the Ahavat Eytan has to say. In the meantime, I think your suggestion about a copyist's error makes good sense!

Comment: For the record: The Tosafot Yom Tov and  עיקר תוי"ט share a name, but are not always in sync. The  עיקר תוי"ט will quote from other sources as well. (Same for the שפתי חכמים and the עיקר ש"ח - they sometimes even argue - though I've forgotten where that is.)

Answer (score -5):

Piggul is obviously TIME but at a different time the PLACE changes also!! So the PLACE acquires a new status due to its relationship to TIME!! It is not through itself as Place but through its relationship to Time that this occurs. In a mundane way, one never steps into the same river twice!!

Comment: Please Aleksander can you explain yourself a bit better. As it is written it seems incomprehensible to me

Comment: To me this clarifies... קדשים שחשב לאכלן חוץ לזמנן או חוץ למקומן!!To me it is the equating of Time and Location or Place. Let us not forget that Makom is used here with all of its overtones and Gematria that connotes it to HaShem. Hopefully, you can extend it from there. This Place is NEVER Karet!! But can become forbidden due to its relationship to Time. The  phrase given was from the Bartenura, not me. I am only trying to explicate why he wrote this and why he is absolutely correct!!